# how to fix evaluation of for looping

Tags: java, php-java-bridge

I have code of javabridge but when I want to rebuild this code, I got an error in this code:
code witch call the code error is here

```
 private <T> SoftReference getReference(final URLClassLoaderEntry entry, final List handlers) {
        if (handlers.isEmpty()) {
            return new SoftReference((T)entry);
        }
        return new DeleteTempFileAction(entry, DynamicClassLoader.TEMP_FILE_QUEUE, handlers);
    }
```

here the code where i got error

```
public DeleteTempFileAction(final Object arg0, final ReferenceQueue arg1, final List handlers) {
            super(arg0, arg1);
            this.handlers = handlers;
            DynamicClassLoader.DELETE_TEMP_FILE_ACTIONS.add(this);
            if (Logger.getLogLevel() > 4) {
                int count = 0;
                int orphaned = 0;
                for (final SoftReference val : DynamicClassLoader.DELETE_TEMP_FILE_ACTIONS) {
                    ++count;
                    if (val.get() == null) {
                        ++orphaned;
                    }
                }
                Logger.logDebug("classloader stats: entries: " + count + " orphaned: " + orphaned);
            }
        }
        
        public void command() {
            for (final DynamicHttpURLConnectionHandler handler : this.handlers) {
                handler.deleteTempFile();
            }
        }
```

At this code I got 2 error there are in:
1.

```
 for (final SoftReference val : DynamicClassLoader.DELETE_TEMP_FILE_ACTIONS) {
                        ++count;
                        if (val.get() == null) {
                            ++orphaned;
                        }
                    }
```

2. for (final DynamicHttpURLConnectionHandler handler : this.handlers) {
   handler.deleteTempFile();
   }

Error for the first code is:

```
Type Missmatch : Cannot convert from element type object to SoftReference
```

Error for the second code is:

```
Type Missmatch : Cannot convert from element type object to DynamicHttpURLConnectionHandler
```

type of DynamicClassLoader.DELETE_TEMP_FILE_ACTIONS is

```
private static final Set DELETE_TEMP_FILE_ACTIONS;
```

and for the second one for
class of DynamicHttpURLConnectionHandler is

```
class DynamicHttpURLConnectionHandler extends URLStreamHandler
{
    private JarFile jarFile;
    private File baseFile;
    private Map headerFields;
    
    public DynamicHttpURLConnectionHandler() {
        if (Logger.getLogLevel() > 4) {
            Logger.logDebug("tempfile create DynamicHttpURLConnectionHander " + this);
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    protected URLConnection openConnection(final URL u) throws IOException {
        return new DynamicJarURLConnection(u, this);
    }
    
    public void deleteTempFile() {
        if (Logger.getLogLevel() > 4) {
            Logger.logDebug("classloader tempfile deleted: " + this.baseFile + " handler: " + this);
        }
        this.baseFile.delete();
    }
    
    public Map getHeaderFields() {
        return this.headerFields;
    }
    
    public JarFile getTempFile() {
        return this.jarFile;
    }
    
    public void setTempFile(final JarFile jarFile, final File baseFile) {
        if (Logger.getLogLevel() > 4) {
            Logger.logDebug("classloader tempfile created: " + baseFile + " handler" + this);
        }
        this.jarFile = jarFile;
        this.baseFile = baseFile;
    }
    
    public void setHeaderFields(final Map headerFields) {
        this.headerFields = headerFields;
    }
}
```

for SoftReference I have this class

public class SoftReference extends Reference {

```
/**
 * Timestamp clock, updated by the garbage collector
 */
static private long clock;

/**
 * Timestamp updated by each invocation of the get method.  The VM may use
 * this field when selecting soft references to be cleared, but it is not
 * required to do so.
 */
private long timestamp;

/**
 * Creates a new soft reference that refers to the given object.  The new
 * reference is not registered with any queue.
 *
 * @param referent object the new soft reference will refer to
 */
public SoftReference(T referent) {
    super(referent);
    this.timestamp = clock;
}

/**
 * Creates a new soft reference that refers to the given object and is
 * registered with the given queue.
 *
 * @param referent object the new soft reference will refer to
 * @param q the queue with which the reference is to be registered,
 *          or <tt>null</tt> if registration is not required
 *
 */
public SoftReference(T referent, ReferenceQueue<? super T> q) {
    super(referent, q);
    this.timestamp = clock;
}

/**
 * Returns this reference object's referent.  If this reference object has
 * been cleared, either by the program or by the garbage collector, then
 * this method returns <code>null</code>.
 *
 * @return   The object to which this reference refers, or
 *           <code>null</code> if this reference object has been cleared
 */
public T get() {
    T o = super.get();
    if (o != null && this.timestamp != clock)
        this.timestamp = clock;
    return o;
}
```

}

i have try to use Set but still got an error

My question is how to fix this problem?

Comment: Note: if you ask about errors you should include them not just the code that produces them. Don't make us guess.

Comment: sorry for that i have update for specific error here,. thanks @Thomas

Comment: Ok, I can't tell about the first error since I don't know the type of `DynamicClassLoader.DELETE_TEMP_FILE_ACTIONS` but it's probably the same as the second error. That one is because you're using a raw type for `handlers`, i.e. instead of a `List<? extends DynamicHttpURLConnectionHandler>` or just `List<DynamicHttpURLConnectionHandler>` you're just using `List` and thus all the compiler knows is that the list contains objects. You might want to read up on Java generics for some more information.

Comment: from the code i have only this one private static final Set DELETE_TEMP_FILE_ACTIONS;   for type of type of DynamicClassLoader.DELETE_TEMP_FILE_ACTIONS @Thomas

Comment: That's what I expected: `Set` instead of `Set<SoftReference>` or `Set<? extends SoftReference>` is the same type of problem. So you either need to add those generics or change the type of the loop vars to `Object` and cast to the respective type you need.

Comment: btw for handlers i don't know specify of this code for. because i just get on github....

Comment: i have use cast like Set<SoftReference> but i still got error here

Comment: i have try using Set<SoftReference> but i still got error here @Thomas

Comment: Well, please read up on Java generics. You'll have to use generics in the method parameters as well or use some ugly casts (which I won't share because you need to know what you're doing when you use those).

Comment: Hi thanks @Thomas this done after i change my code become this private static final Set<SoftReference> DELETE_TEMP_FILE_ACTIONS;